# Getting index and value of a reoccurrence/repeat of an element in a list/array (Py3)

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I've a numpy.ndarray (or list of list) and I want to find index and value of the entries if they reoccur/repeat in the array, BUT NOT if they follow up on each other.

A code to produce the array:

```
import numpy as np

dims = 2

n = 11
set = [-1, 0, 1]
origin = np.zeros((1,dims))

shape = (n,dims)
steps = np.random.choice(a=set, size=shape)
path = np.concatenate([origin, steps]).cumsum(0)

print(path)
```

With (an) output:

```
[[ 0.  0.][ 1.  0.][ 2. -1.][ 2.  0.][ 2.  0.][ 2.  0.][ 2. -1.][ 2. -1.][ 1.  0.][ 1. -1.][ 1.  0.][ 0.  0.]]
```

So what I want at end for this case would be:
`index: 6 value: [ 2.  -1.]`

as this is the first value pair, that reoccurs in the list (index 2 and 6) but doesn't follow up on each other, like e.g. `[ 2.  0.]` at index 3,4,5.

I'm totally lost on how to tackle this problem. Any help is appreciated. It would be helpful if the style of the code could stay similar.

Thanks to you all!

Comment: probably you will have to use two `for`-loops - external loop to get element which you want to find, internal loop to get element to compare. You could also use `set()` in external loop to every value only once.

Comment: BTW: you could add `np.random.seed(0)` and then we can work always with the same example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used two `for`-loops

```
import numpy as np

a = [[ 0.,  0.],[ 1.,  0.],[ 2., -1.],[ 2.,  0.],[ 2.,  0.],[ 2.,  0.],
     [ 2., -1.],[ 2., -1.],[ 1.,  0.],[ 1., -1.],[ 1.,  0.],[ 0.,  0.]]

arr = np.array(a)

for x, item in enumerate(arr, 0):
    for y, compare in enumerate(arr[x+2:], x+2):
        if (item == compare).all():
            print(item, x, y)
```

and get

```
[0. 0.]   0 11
[1. 0.]   1 8
[1. 0.]   1 10
[ 2. -1.] 2 6
[ 2. -1.] 2 7
[2. 0.]   3 5
[1. 0.]   8 10
```

Comment: Perfect. That will do the job. Thank you. I totally forgot about the all()/any() methods.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

Input:

```
sample = [(0.,  0.), (1., 0.), (2., -1.), (2.,  0.),
          (2.,  0.), (2.,  0.), (2., -1.), (2., -1.),
          (1.,  0.), (1., -1.), (1.,  0.), (0.,  0.)]

def non_repeating_dups(sample):
    duplicates = set(sample[0])
    for index, window in enumerate(windowed(sample, 2)):
        if window[1] in duplicates and window[0] != window[1]:
            return index + 1, window[1]
        duplicates.add(window[1])

non_repeating_dups(sample)
```

Output:

```
(6, (2.0, -1.0))
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks really nice, but could you elaborate what "windowed()" is and does? I can't find a documentation. NVM! I found that it is imported from more_itertools

Comment: While it looks neat, I can't get it transformed to work for my case, where I do not have a list of tuples.